# How to bypass the implicit wait condition while looking for webelement which is not present on UI?

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, implicitwait

I am automating a scenario wherein a specific web element might or might not be displayed on the UI. If it is getting displayed, then I want to perform a specific action on it. I am using below logic for the same

```
try{
if(element.isDisplayed())
    {
     //perform action on the element if it is visible
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
```

The code works fine whenever the element is visible on the UI. But during scenarios when the element is not displayed, then 'element.isDisplayed()' waits for the element for 10 seconds (i.e the implicit wait time which I have defined for the driver session).

I want my script to not wait for that 10 seconds for the element to appear, instead just go ahead with further actions. Any idea what approach should I go with here?

Comment: The difficulty with validating items are NOT present is that you cannot be certain if it's not there, or not there YET (e.g. you  wait 10s and it appears after 11 seconds), or your element identifier is now wrong and it it is there but you miss it - and you never know!....  There are different approaches to this, easiest is to only use objects that are present. Another is to create a method where you tell it if it will/will not be present and adjust timings accordingly based on negative/positive and how long you're willing to wait.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you can achieve with decrease timeout value utilize `WebDriverWait`.

Try to create a boolean function to check the element presence or not with specific time.

```
public boolean checkElement(By locator, int seconds) {
    boolean find = false;
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        find = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return find;
}
```

Just call with:

```
By locator = By.name("yourLocator");

if(checkElement(locator, 1)) {
    //perform here
    ....
}
```

The following imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Please delete `implicitWait` which you've declared before.